# Firebase Analytics key and value limitation to 24 and 36 character

Tags: google-analytics, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-analytics

Why do google has limitations in keys and values to 24 and 36 characters? What is the best implementation to overcome it.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Now you can log firebase analytics Event param name up to 40 characters and value up to 100 characters

See documentation here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/group/parameter-names

Comment: For iOS: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/FIRAnalytics It also says 100 chars max.

Comment: Yes, the same limitation for both platforms.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason for the value size limits is to ensure minimal impact on the device battery, low device storage requirement, low network bandwidth usage and make the data more manageable for the infrastructure and BigQuery.

We might consider increasing the value limits if there is valid reasons to do so. What is the case where you need longer values?

Comment: App developers need to log event values such as: URL's, String arrays (list of chosen categories for example), titles of articles read, etc, etc. 36 chars is ridiculous.

Comment: We are looking to allow longer values. Either way you won't be able to log large data as dictionary of things. Params are not meant to be used as general purpose storage. Other things, like audiences, in the system will not work well with complex data either. What are you hoping to learn from logging a list of values?

Comment: I have 15-20 categories of content the users can choose from. I want to know which categories each user choose to follow and also to know what are the most popular categories overall.

Comment: Why not create a bit filed and set it as user property? Sending list ot strings with every event is very inefficient way to represent the data. Keep in mind that even though the data is compressed it still needs to be send over the wire. On metered connection your user is paying for the data.

Comment: text data is redundant, even if the size would be 1024, it's less than 5kb, every image in the app takes x100 more than that. Also you forgot that Product Manager types wants to look at the data, not just developers. Dashboard with bitmap is not very "user friendly"

Comment: Is there a public bug tracker for Firebase Analytics like there is for BigQuery? Ignoring all other use cases, search_term, item_category, destination, and item_name, which are examples given in the docs, do not often fit in 36 characters.  For publishers, article URL and article title also are often over 36 characters.